# ajax jquery post not working in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a grid kind of div in html in which I am doing some records.
If clicked on edit, a pop up opens and user can edit the record and the data will be saved to database. Upon saving the data, my grid should refresh.

All these calls to mvc controllers we are doing using ajax, but the grid is not refreshing. some problem in ajay post, the success method for "refreshRules" is never fired, where it works fine for other actions like "saveMetricRule" , "metricruleeditor"

can somebody advise me what am I doing wrong here?

below is the jquery code block:

```
var m_oConfig = {

        editMetricRule: {
            ds: "/stealth/metricruleeditor",
            p: function (config, elem) { return YAHOO.stealth.editMetricRuleP(config, elem); },
            s: function (axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR) { YAHOO.stealth.editRuleS(axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR); }
        },

        saveMetricRule: {
            ds: "/stealth/saveMetricRule",
            p: function (config, elem) { return YAHOO.stealth.saveMetricRuleP(config, elem); },


            s: function (axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR) { YAHOO.stealth.saveMetricRuleS(axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR); }
        },

        refreshRules: {
            ds: "/stealth/metricsrefresh",
            p: function (config, elem) { return YAHOO.stealth.refreshRulesP(config, elem); },
            s: function (axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR) { YAHOO.stealth.refreshRulesS(axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR); }
        }

refreshRulesP: function (config, elem) {
        return {
            gid: $(elem).attr("data-gid"),
        };
    },
    refreshRulesS: function (axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var sRoot = "rules";

        $("#" + sRoot).replaceWith(data);

        YAHOO.stealth.bindMetricGrids(sRoot);
    },


    saveMetricRuleP: function (config, elem) {
        var sErrMsg = "There are errors in the rule.";

        //rErr class added during any change
        if ($(".rErr").length) {
            //update rule pop-in
            YAHOO.stealth.ErrHndlr(sErrMsg, "pnlRuleError");

            //cancel ajax (and update actual page)
            throw "";
        }

        //return the rule
        return {
            rule: YAHOO.stealth.getRuleObj()
        };
    },

    saveMetricRuleS: function (axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //close the pop-in
        CSUtils.DisablePop();

        //refresh the rules
        YAHOO.stealth.loadNaked("refreshRules", null, elem);

        //Indicate to user that they must run the rules
        YAHOO.stealth.needRuleRun(data.msg, elem);
    },


 loadNaked: function (axn, config, elem) {
        if (BlockAjax
            || (!axn || axn == "")) { return; }

        var oAxn = m_oConfig[axn];

        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: oAxn.ds,
                data: JSON.stringify(oAxn.p(config, elem)),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('s');
                    //if they defined a success function (s), call it with all the init and return data
                    if (typeof oAxn.s === "function") {
                        oAxn.s(axn, config, elem, data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    }

                    //any dependent actions need to be called as well
                    if (oAxn.deps && oAxn.deps.length > 0) {
                        $.each(oAxn.deps, function (idx, dep) {
                            YAHOO.stealth.loadNaked(dep, config, elem);
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (err, type, msg) {
                    YAHOO.stealth.ErrHndlr(err.responseText);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {

            if (err && err !== "") {
                YAHOO.stealth.ErrHndlr(err.responseText);
            }

            BlockAjax = false; //if it was set, we should unset it
        }
    },
```

controller actions:

```
  public ActionResult metricsrefresh(int gid)
    {
        UIGrid oGrid = this.metricRulesGrid(gid);

        string myString = RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext , MVCConstants.VIEW_LISTABLE, this.metricRulesGrid(gid));

        return this.Json(new
        {
            myString 
        });

    }


    public ActionResult saveMetricRule(Rule rule)
    {
        bool IsNew = rule.RuleId  == 0;

        using (NewAngieDataContext oAngieCtxt = new NewAngieDataContext(new CSConfigurationMgr().GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringKey.Angie)))
        {
            if (IsNew)
                oAngieCtxt.Rules.InsertOnSubmit(rule);
            else
            {
                RuleCondition oRuleCon = null;
                foreach (RuleCondition childItem in rule.RuleConditions)
                {
                    oRuleCon =
                           oAngieCtxt.RuleConditions
                                .Where(CON => CON.RuleConditionId == childItem.RuleConditionId )
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                    oRuleCon.Points = childItem.Points;
                    oRuleCon.ConditionValue = childItem.ConditionValue;
                    oRuleCon.ToOperatorId = childItem.ToOperatorId;
                    oRuleCon.Sort = childItem.Sort;
                }

                oAngieCtxt.Rules.Attach(rule);
                oAngieCtxt.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, rule);
            }
            oAngieCtxt.SubmitChanges();
        }

        return this.Json(new
        {
            msg = "Successful save.",
            ruleId = rule.RuleId
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is actually working in the site that is deployed. but not working in localhost, may be because the post action symbols doesnt not load in debug mode, any view on this?

Comment: Too much code. Could you create smaller sample?

Answer (score 0):

If this is working on production and not on the localhost, that would indicate that the URLs of where you are posting the data are absolute, instead of relative to the site root (details below the proposed solution).

You could try replacing the absolute URLs with dynamically created URLs on the server. I.e. instead of this in your JavaScript:

```
editMetricRule: {
        ds: "/stealth/metricruleeditor",
```

try something like this:

```
editMetricRule: {
        ds: @Url.Action("metricruleeditor", "stealth"),
```

It's a good practice to do this anyway ;)

---

**Details:**

So, it works on the server where your root might be:

```
http://myserver.com/
```

so, this `/stealth/metricruleeditor` becomes:

```
http://myserver.com/stealth/metricruleeditor
```

But, on the localhost your root could be:

```
http://localhost/myAppName
```

and the correct URL to post data is:

```
http://localhost/myAppName/stealth/metricruleeditor
```

but, "/stealth/metricruleeditor" in your JS translates to:

```
http://localhost/stealth/metricruleeditor
```

You can confirm this by looking at the dev tools in your browser and monitoring the network traffic: requests and server responses.